# Identificar execução de arquivo dentro de um ZIP

Tags: c#, winforms, arquivo-zip

Eu criei um aplicativo que foi disponibilizado para download dentro de um `.zip`. Dentro do `.zip` tem um `.exe` e alguns arquivos necessários para realizar uma instalação. Até ai tudo certo.

Porém alguns usuários não realizam a extração dos arquivos antes de instalar, eles executam o arquivo `.exe` diretamente de dentro do `.zip`. Ista gera um erro pois o aplicativo não consegue encontrar os arquivos necessários para prosseguir com a instalação.

Então a minha dúvida é a seguinte: **Como eu faço para identificar se o meu aplicativo está sendo executado de dentro de um `.zip`?**

*Considerações:*

1) Por necessitar de uma solução rápida eu não posso colocar tudo dentro de um `.msi` ou como recursos incorporados no `.exe`. Isto implicaria em alterar o aplicativo que no momento não é uma boa opção.

2) Estou usando C# + VS 2012 com Windows Forms

Comment: Porque não cria um SFX ou um EXE do winzip.

Comment: Até onde sei, quando executamos os EXE dentro do arquivo zip, o Winrar, por exemplo, descompacta na pasta temp do windows.
Compartilha o erro que da quando é executado o teu sistema dentro do zip.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: @PabloVargas o aplicativo não dá erro, ele verifica antes de iniciar a instalação se os arquivos existem, caso não exista ele não prossegue. Mas os arquivos podem não existir por mais de um motivo, não apenas pelo fato de estar em uma pasta temp.

Comment: por acaso o teu executável não tem os caminhos de arquivos fixo?

Comment: @PabloVargas Não são caminhos fixos, são relativos a pasta de execução do aplicativo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução que encontrei para a solução do meu problema foi criar um executável que continha o arquivo zip com todos os arquivos e colocar ele como `Recurso incorporado` ou `Embedded resource` e realizar a extração do conteúdo e iniciar o executável do zip na sequência.

Sei que existem opções melhores, como a utilização de instaladores de ampla utilização no mercado, mas por algumas particularidades do software não foi possível fazer isto.

Answer (score 0):

Seu processo ta certo. Um tecnico deveria fazer a instalação do soft, seja ele seu ou da empresa cliente. Isso é um erro no procedimento de instalação por parte do usuário. O que você deve fazer é colocar uma observação quando o usuário baixar seu soft. A maioria sabe que deve descompactar antes de executar o instalador, mas é claro sempre tem os desinformados.

Comment: Nesse caso como o software é para cliente final, não teria a necessidade de ter um técnico sempre disponível para executar a instalação.